# Akka actor - messaging neighbours

Tags: scala, akka, actor

Consider that i have four actors(1,2,3,4) in a same actor system.Each actor can send message only with its neighbors who has not sent a message to it(i.e. 1 can send only to 2 and 4. Also 2 and 4 can only send to 3 because their neighbor 1 has already sent a message). when an actor receives message from both its neighbors, it prints its name and the system stops.I am able to partially implement.But issue here is in the same time two actors gets message from both their neighbors and stops.For example, if i start the process at 1, 1 sends message to 4 and 2,2 to 3 and 4 to 3 so theoretically 3 should get printed but i get 2 and 3 both printed.Please suggest what can be done.Below is my sample logic.

```
object Main extends App {

  //creating a actor system
  val actorSystem = ActorSystem("System")
  //creating four actor instances with id as 1,2,3,4
  for (i <- 1 to 4) {
    actorSystem.actorOf(CircularActor.props(4), "" + i)
  }
  //initiating message to actor 1
  actorSystem.actorSelection(s"/user/1") ! "hello from x"
}


class CircularActor(n: Int) extends Actor {

  //variable to keep a track whether the actor received two meesages(i.e.from both neighbours)
  var noOfMessagesReceived = 0

  //generic method to send message using actorPath
  def messageNeighbour(path:String){
    context.actorSelection(path) ! "hello from x"
  }

  override def receive: Receive = {

    case "hello from x" =>
      noOfMessagesReceived += 1
      if (noOfMessagesReceived == 2) {
        println(s"The actor that received both messages is ${self.path.name}")
        context.system.terminate()
      }
      else {
        //Figures out id of sender
        val pathValue = sender().path.name
        //Gets its own name
        val ownId = self.path.name.toInt
        //Finds out the previous neighbor
        val prev = if (ownId - 1 == 0) n else ownId - 1
        //Finds next neighbour
        val next = if (ownId == n) 1 else ownId + 1

        //If the message is from deadletter, then this is the initiator actor
        if (pathValue == "deadLetters") {
          messageNeighbour(s"/user/$prev")
          messageNeighbour(s"/user/$next")
        }
        //If the message is from its next neighbour,send it to previous
        else if (pathValue.toInt == next) {
          //introducing random delay
          Thread.sleep(1 + Random.nextInt(100))
          messageNeighbour(s"/user/$prev")
        }
        //If none of above,then send it to previous.
        else {
          Thread.sleep(1 + Random.nextInt(100))
          messageNeighbour(s"/user/$next")
        }
  }
}

object CircularActor {

  def props(n: Int): Props = Props(new CircularActor(n))
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be that you assume that messages are processed in the order in which they are sent, which is not necessarily the case. Message passing is asynchronous, and the only guarantee is that messages are processed **in the order that they arrive** for any given actor. The order in which messages are processed by different actors is not defined.

So in your system the messages could be processed in this order

```
<dead> -> 1
     1 -> 2,4
     4 -> 3
     3 -> 2
     2 -> 3
     2 -> <terminate>
```

As you can see, actor `2` processes two messages before any other actor.

It is not clear what can be done because it is not clear what you are trying to achieve. But it is dangerous to build actor systems with loops like this. In general, an actor system should be organised as a tree or DAG of requests, with replies sent to the requesting actor.

Comment: There is no specific use case. All I am trying to find out, who is the first person to receive message from both its neighbors. Can this be achieved?

Comment: @SugaRaj Your code does do that, but theoretically it could be any  of the actors that is the first to receive two messages. I am not sure why you get two lines printed, it may be that the actor system does not shut down immediately when `terminate()` is called.

Comment: I am still trying to figure out why the two print statements in console. Please let me know if you figure out by any change

Answer (score 0):

To achieve required behavior we need an actor for tracking the actors to which messages are received.

Model:

```
abstract class Direction

object Left extends Direction

object Right extends Direction

object StartPoint extends Direction

object Process
```

BookKeeper Actor

```
class BookKeeperActor extends Actor {
var visitedActorRefs: mutable.HashSet[String] = mutable.HashSet.empty[String]

override def receive: Receive = {
  case Process =>
    if (visitedActorRefs.contains(sender().path.toString)) {
      context.stop(self)
      context.system.terminate()
      println(s"The actor that received both messages is ${sender().path.toString}")
    }
    else
      visitedActorRefs.add(sender().path.toString)
}

}
```

Circular Actor:

```
class CircularActor(n: Int, bookKeeper: ActorRef) extends Actor {


//generic method to send message using actorPath
def messageNeighbour(path: String, direction: Direction) {
  context.actorSelection(path) ! ("hello from x", direction)
}

override def receive: Receive = {


  case ("hello from x", direction: Direction) =>
    bookKeeper ! Process
    //Figures out id of sender
    val pathValue = sender().path.name
    //Gets its own name
    val ownId = self.path.name.toInt
    //Finds out the previous neighbor
    val prev = if (ownId - 1 == 0) n else ownId - 1
    //Finds next neighbour
    val next = if (ownId == n) 1 else ownId + 1

    Thread.sleep(1 + Random.nextInt(100))

    direction match {
      case StartPoint =>
        messageNeighbour(s"/user/$prev", Left)
        messageNeighbour(s"/user/$next", Right)
      case Left => messageNeighbour(s"/user/$prev", Left)
      case Right => messageNeighbour(s"/user/$next", Right)
    }

}

}


object CircularActor {

def props(n: Int, bookeeper: ActorRef): Props = Props(new CircularActor(n, bookeeper))
}
```

Main App-

```
object Main extends App {

val actorSystem = ActorSystem("System")
//creating four actor instances with id as 1,2,3,4
val bookKeeperActor = actorSystem.actorOf(Props(new BookKeeperActor))
for (i <- 1 to 4) {
  val ac = actorSystem.actorOf(CircularActor.props(4, bookKeeperActor), "" + i)
}
//initiating message to actor 1
actorSystem.actorSelection(s"/user/1") ! ("hello from x", StartPoint)
}
```